# Fastest way to retrieve an item by title?

Tags: splistitem

Currently I am using  a foreach loop to find the item I want by its title using the following code:

```
                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("DocumentLibrary");
                foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Title == "Title")
                        return true;
                }
```

Is there a faster way to do this? Perhaps a CAML query?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also use SPQuery and a CAML query, like below. I also agree with what Dave Wise said about PortalSiteMapProvider class.

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">YourTitle</Value></Eq></Where>";
query.RowLimit = 1;
query.ViewFields = "";
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
SPListItem item = items[0];
```

Comment: It should also be noted the PortalSiteMapProvider class only improves performance if the data is changed infrequently. Here's an excerpt from the article provided by @Dave Wise:

"Also, using the above methods to fetch data which frequently changes can also be counterproductive. If the data changes frequently, it will be frequently invalidated and re-fetched from that database negating the benefits of caching. The invalidation mechanism is relatively coarse, with a change to a particular item invalidating any data in the same web as the item."

Comment: Take care in the query it's `</Eq>` before `</Where>`. They're a mistake here. query.Query = "<Where>" + "<Eq>" + "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/>" + "<Value Type=\"Text\">YourTitle</Value>" + "</Eq>" + "</Where>"; query.ViewFields = "";

Answer (score 6):

The [PortalSiteMapProvider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2007/05/23/increased-performance-for-moss-apps-using-the-portalsitemapprovider.aspx) is the fastest way to access content and you should be able to do what you need with that.